# Role-Based Authentication in Next.js (v13.4) - Is Using a Loader to Prevent Unauthorized Page Access Appropriate?

Tags: next.js, next-router

I'm relatively new to Next.js and am in the process of creating a role-based application using the latest version, Next.js 13.4. For role-based authentication, I've implemented it using a Higher-Order Component (HOC).

**Here's what I've done so far:**

**Unauthorized Page Access Handling:** When an unauthorized user attempts to access a restricted page, I've set up the application to navigate them to a "permission denied" page. However, I've noticed that before the navigation occurs, the unauthorized page briefly appears for a second.

**Loader:** To prevent this issue, I've added a loader. This loader seems to work in preventing unauthorized users from briefly viewing restricted content before being redirected to the "permission denied" page.

My question is whether the loader approach I've taken is appropriate for handling unauthorized page access, or if there are more effective methods to achieve this in Next.js, particularly in version 13.4. If you've encountered a similar situation or have insights into better practices, please share your expertise. I'd appreciate any guidance to ensure a smoother user experience in terms of unauthorized access prevention. Thank you!

`Higher Order Component`

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter, usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import roles from "@/utils/routs";
import { isLoginReducer } from "@/redux/features/authSlice";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Loader from "@/components/elements/Loader";

const UseRoleHook = (Component: any) => {
  return function ProtectedRoute() {
    // Get user role and login status from Redux store
    const { role, isLogin } = useSelector(
      (state: { authPersistedReducer: { role: string; isLogin: boolean } }) =>
        state.authPersistedReducer
    );

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const pathname = usePathname();
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
      // Check if the user is not logged in
      if (!isLogin) {
        // If the role is "admin", "superAdmin", or "user", set login status to true and redirect to the home page
        if (role === "admin" || role === "superAdmin" || role === "user") {
          dispatch(isLoginReducer(true)); // Dispatch the action to update the login state
          router.push("/");
        } else {
          router.push("/login"); // Redirect the user to the login page if the role is not recognized
        }
      } else {
        // If the user is logged in
        // Check if the current pathname is allowed for the user's role
        if (!roles[role]?.path.includes(pathname)) {
          // If not allowed, throw an error indicating "Permission Denied"
          throw new Error("Permission Denied");
        } else {
          // If allowed, redirect the user to the current pathname
          router.push(pathname);
        }
      }
    }, [isLogin, role, pathname]);

    if (!roles[role]?.path.includes(pathname)) {
      // If not, return a loading spinner using the Loader component while the correct route is loaded
      return (
        // Or display a loading spinner or message
        <div className="w-full h-screen flex justify-center items-center">
          <Loader />
        </div>
      );
    }

    return <Component />;
  };
};

export default UseRoleHook;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using useEffect hook and it is `asynchronous` in nature. You should use `useLayoutEffect` hook which is `synchronous` in nature. When you authenticate the user it will stop to return the `JSX` unless until user is confirmed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this approach didn't work as I expected. And this approach also gives the same issue.